# Evaluating values within a dictionary for different keys

Tags: python, dictionary, difference

I have a nested dictionary to which I would like to obtain the differences between each value.

```
locsOne = {1:[100], 2:[200], 3:[250]}
```

(these values here are just examples)
I'm attempting to apply a abs(-) function to each key:value to get the distance between each and create a dictionary with the results. How I'd like the results to be formatted would be:

```
locsTwo = {1:{2:100, 3:150}, 2:{1:100, 3:50}, 3:{1:150, 2: 50 }}
```

My current attempt is:

```
for i in range(len(listOne)):
    if abs(listOne[i] - listTwo[i]) >= 450:
        pass
    else:
        distances.append(abs(listOne[i] - listTwo[i]))
```

Kind of at a loss on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I'm checking if the difference is greater that 450 in the loop so that any values that differ greater than 450 are discarded / not included in our result set.

Comment: why are you checking, if the difference is greater than 450? You didnt mention it anywhere

Comment: @kecer thanks for spotting that! I've made an edit to include that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locsOne = {1:[100], 2:[200], 3:[250]}
locsTwo = {}
for k1 in locsOne:
    v1 = locsOne[k1][0]
    locsTwo[k1] = {k2: abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) for k2 in locsOne
                   if k1 != k2 and abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) <= 450}
print(locsTwo)
```

output:

```
{1: {2: 100, 3: 150}, 2: {1: 100, 3: 50}, 3: {1: 150, 2: 50}}
```

Comment: `locsTwo[k1] = {k2: abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) for k2 in locsOne if k1 != k2 and abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0])<450}`, honoring OP's update

Comment: @kecer + falsetru, these both work great. Thank you both so much!

Comment: @falsetru if I were to have a dictionary of locsOne = {[1, 'city 1 1', 25, [[-6.259859035513058, 53.33695129809404]], [2, 'city 2', 25, [[-6.259859035513058, 53.33695129809404]]} is there a way to change your solution to consider this? Thanks!

Comment: @BenW, It's not a valid dictionary. Where are keys?