# Referencing nested dictionary keys and values in dict comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I asked this question earlier today:  [Evaluating values within a dictionary for different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593335/evaluating-values-within-a-dictionary-for-different-keys/25593380)

The structure of the dictionary I'm working with has changed and I've attempted to modify the solution I was given to accommodate this.

The structure before was:

```
locsOne = {1: [100], 2: [200], 3: [250]}
```

but now it has been changed to:

```
locsone = {1: [[100]], 2: [[200]], 3: [[250]]}
```

I'm attempting to apply a haversine formula on the locsOne dictionary, get the key:value's distance to the other key:values and if they are greater than 450, they should not be included in the results dictionary.

The resulting dictionary should look like this:

```
locsTwo = {1: {2: 100, 3: 150}, 2: {1: 100, 3: 50}, 3: {1: 150, 2: 50}}
```

This is the code which I received (thanks to falsetru):

```
for k1 in locsOne:
    v1 = locsOne[k1][0]
    locsTwo[k1] = {k2: abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) for k2 in locsOne
                   if k1 != k2 and abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) <= 450}
print(locsTwo)
```

My attempts at modifying it return errors such as "IndexError: list out of range" and "KeyError".

My last modification is:

```
for k1 in locsOne:
        v1 = locsOne[k1][1]
        locsTwo[k1] = {k2: harvesineForm(v1 , locsOne[k2][1]) for k2 in locsOne
                   if k1 != k2 and abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0]) <= 450}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[100]]
print a       # [[100]]
print a[0]    # [100]
print a[0][0] # 100
```

Following the assumption that the values always contain a single value in a list, nested in a list:

```
locsOne = {1: [[100]], 2: [[200]], 3: [[250]]}
locsTwo = {}

for k1 in locsOne:
    v1 = locsOne[k1][0][0]
    locsTwo[k1] = {k2: abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0][0]) for k2 in locsOne
                   if k1 != k2 and abs(v1 - locsOne[k2][0][0]) <= 450}
print(locsTwo)
```

You simply have to access the first value (`[0]`) of the list again, since you have one more level of lists.

Comment: if the values contained a coordinate such as [-36393612 , 28623927] (just as an example), would there be a way to adjust your suggestion to accommodate this? I'm currently getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'".

Comment: What would the dict look like exactly, `{1: [-1, 1]}` or `{1: [[-1, 1]]}`? Or even `{1: [[-1], [1]]}`? Just to make sure: you only get the error when the list contains more than one element, right?

Comment: It looks like this: {1:[[-6.26373252, 54.33636358]], 2:[[-6.5463247, 54.4578952]]}

Comment: And what shall the output look like? It would help if you either directly ask for what you want or build up on what we give you yourself.